# How to replace a string like "[1.0 - 4.0]" with a numeric value using awk or sed?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a CSV file that I am piping through a set of awk/sed commands.

Some lines in the CSV file look like this:

```
10368,"Verizon DSL",DSL,NY,NORTHEAST,-5,-4,"[1.1 - 3.0]","[0.384 - 0.768]"
```

where the 8th and 9th columns are a string representing a numeric range.

How can I use `awk` or `sed` to replace those fields with a numeric value? Either the beginning of the range, or the end of the range?

So this line would end up as

```
10368,"Verizon DSL",DSL,NY,NORTHEAST,-5,-4,1.1,0.384
```

or

```
10368,"Verizon DSL",DSL,NY,NORTHEAST,-5,-4,3.0,0.768
```

I got as far as [removing the brackets](https://serverfault.com/questions/466118/using-sed-to-remove-both-an-opening-and-closing-square-bracket-around-a-string) but past that I'm stuck. I considered splitting on the " - ", but many lines in my file have a regular numeric value, not a range, in those last two columns, and that makes things messy (I don't want to end up with some lines having a different number of columns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sed command that will take each range and break it up into two fields. It looks for strings like `"[A - B]"` and converts them to `A,B`. It can easily be modified to just use one of the values if needed by changing the `\1,\2` portion. The regular expression assumes that all numbers have at least one digit on either side of a required decimal place. So, `1`, `.5`, and `3.` would not be valid. If you need that, the regex can be made to be more accommodating.

```
$ cat file
10368,"Verizon DSL",DSL,NY,NORTHEAST,-5,-4,"[1.1 - 3.0]","[0.384 - 0.768]"
$ sed -Ee 's|"\[([0-9]+\.[0-9]+) - ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\]"|\1,\2|g' file
10368,"Verizon DSL",DSL,NY,NORTHEAST,-5,-4,1.1,3.0,0.384,0.768
```

Comment: That "\1,\2" thing is new to me, I did not know you could do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is *field*-based, `awk` is the logical choice.

Note that while `awk` generally isn't aware of *double-quoted* fields, that is not a problem here, because the double-quoted fields do not have *embedded* `,` instances.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

useStart1=1  # set to `0` to use the *end* of the *penultimate* fields' range instead.
useStart2=1  # set to `0` to use the *end* of the *last* field's range instead.
awk -v useStart1=$useStart1 -v useStart2=$useStart2 '
  BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
  { 
        split($(NF-1), tokens1, /[][" -]+/)
        split($NF,     tokens2, /[][" -]+/)
        $(NF-1) = useStart1 ? tokens1[2] : tokens1[3]
        $NF =     useStart2 ? tokens2[2] : tokens2[3]
        print
  }
' <<'EOF'
10368,"Verizon DSL",DSL,NY,NORTHEAST,-5,-4,"[1.1 - 3.0]","[0.384 - 0.768]"
EOF
```

The code above yields:

```
10368,"Verizon DSL",DSL,NY,NORTHEAST,-5,-4,1.1,0.384
```

Modifying the values of `$useStart1` and `$useStart2` yields the appropriate variations.