# String matching with gensub in Awk

Tags: awk

I tried to answer the question  asked here 
[How to replace a string like "[1.0 - 4.0]" with a numeric value using awk or sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687702/how-to-replace-a-string-like-1-0-4-0-with-a-numeric-value-using-awk-or-sed)

I tried for

```
awk  '{ print gensub(/[([0-9]+.[0-9]+) - ([0-9]+.[0-9]+)]/,"\\1","g")}'
```

but it didn't work cant understand why . Please advise.

Input given :

```
10368,"Verizon DSL",DSL,NY,NORTHEAST,-5,-4,"[1.1 - 3.0]","[0.384 - 0.768]"
```

desired output :

```
10368,"Verizon DSL",DSL,NY,NORTHEAST,-5,-4,1.1,0.384
```

Comment: I have the same input  and output  given in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687702/how-to-replace-a-string-like-1-0-4-0-with-a-numeric-value-using-awk-or-sed  , I executed above command but I did not replace anything just printed the input in the output (output string was same as input string )  so I think my command did not do anything

Comment: have edited the question with Input and output

Comment: The square brackets are metacharacters. If you want to match them you need to escape them. Pay attention on the Harvery's solution in the pointed question and how the square brackets are escaped. Your `awk` code, instead, does not contain escaped brackets.

Comment: @Alexandre N. regarding [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15012022), it should not be neither AWK nor awk, but `Awk`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Comment: @fedorqui thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using bracket expressions with `[0-9]` so obviously you know what `[...]` means in a regexp. Now take a look at the regexp you wrote:

```
[([0-9]+.[0-9]+) - ([0-9]+.[0-9]+)]
```

and note where opening `[` and closing `]` characters occur to define the bracket expressions, in particular the first matching pair (the 2nd `[` in the regexp is just a literal `[` character inside the first bracket expression):

```
[([0-9]
+.
[0-9]
+) - (
[0-9]
+.
[0-9]
+)]
```

and note that the last `]` is not terminating a bracket expression so it's already just a literal `]` character and wouldn't need to be escaped.

Also note that the `.`s are regexp metacharacters that match any single character when you really wanted them to be treated literally and according to your expected output you dont want the double quotes retained so your code should have been:

```
$ awk  '{ print gensub(/"\[([0-9]+\.[0-9]+) - ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)]"/,"\\1","g")}' file
10368,"Verizon DSL",DSL,NY,NORTHEAST,-5,-4,1.1,0.384
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, the reason I did not care to escape the the brackets and .s  is that I was able to match the string  in a grep expression  see this    grep  -o '"[[0-9]\{1,\}.[0-9]\{1,\} - [0-9]\{1,\}.[0-9]\{1,\}]"'  I have not escaped the  [   and ]  and  the .s  but yet  it is matching the string that I want to replace So I though that the same expression will also work in awk . Why such difference ? or I am again missing something .

Comment: Your grep regexp doesn't contain the round brackets that identify capture groups/regexp sub-expressions when used in the context of `([foo]bar)` but identify an optional literal `(` followed by a required literal `)` when used as `[(foo]bar)` as you have in your incorrectly specified awk regexp. Hopefully you understand you do still have to do the escaping I suggested to avoid false matches.

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets are metacharacters. If you want to match them you need to escape them.

Pay attention on the Harvery's solution in the pointed question and how the square brackets are escaped. Your awk code, instead, does not contain escaped brackets.

This should work

```
awk  '{ print gensub(/\[([0-9]+.[0-9]+) - ([0-9]+.[0-9]+)\]/,"\\1","g")}'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a sed version

```
$ sed -r '{ s#"\[([0-9.]*)[^"]*"#\1#g }'

10368,"Verizon DSL",DSL,NY,NORTHEAST,-5,-4,1.1,0.384
```